# nhibernate <subclass><join> nest another sublass mapping (cause duplicate insertion of leaf class)

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

What's wrong with this mapping?
On saving an instance of Class3, two rows in Table_2 will be inserted!

first row has Column4 set to null and correct value of Column3, 
and second row has Column3 set to null and correct value of Column4!

```
  <class name="Class1" table="Table_1">
    <id name="Column1">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <discriminator column="ColumnDisc" />
    <property name="Column2" type="int" />
    <subclass name="Class2">
       <join table="Table_2">
         <key column="Column1" />
         <property name="Column3" type="int" />
       </join>
       <subclass name="Class3" >
          <join table="Table_2">
            <key column="Column1" />
            <property name="Column4" type="int" />
          </join>
       </subclass>
    </subclass>
  </class>
```

Comment: That does not look like a valid mapping.

Comment: It is.I've tested what I said.

Comment: Hibernate does implement this scenario as stated in the last section of this article:
http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18300.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you set the discriminator value for each of the derived types?

If I believe the link to which you pointed in your comment, the class mapping looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.javalobby.tnt.hib.User" table="USER" lazy="false">
        <id name="id" type="long" column="ID">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

    <discriminator column="type" type="string"/>

    <property name="firstName" column="first_name"/>
    <property name="lastName" column="last_name"/>

    <subclass name="com.javalobby.tnt.hib.Employee" discriminator-value="employee">
        <join table="employee">
            <key column="id"/>
            <property name="jobTitle" column="job_title"/>
            <many-to-one name="supervisor" column="supervisor_id" not-null="true" />
        </join>
        <subclass name="com.javalobby.tnt.hib.Employer" discriminator-value="employer">
            <set name="subordinates">
                <key column="supervisor_id" not-null="true"/>
                <one-to-many class="com.javalobby.tnt.hib.Employee"/>
            </set>
            <join table="employer">
                <key column="id"/>
                <property name="companyCarBrand" column="company_car_brand"/>
            </join>
        </subclass>
    </subclass>
</class>
```

If I compare your mapping with this one, you lack `discriminator-value` attribute within your `<subclass>` tag.

```
<class name="Class1" table="Table_1">
    <id name="Column1">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <discriminator column="ColumnDisc" />

    <property name="Column2" type="int" />

    <subclass name="Class2"> <!-- The discriminator-value="" is missing here... -->
      <join table="Table_2">
        <key column="Column1" />
        <property name="Column3" type="int" />
      </join>
      <subclass name="Class3" > <!-- The discriminator-value="" is missing here... -->
        <join table="Table_2">
          <key column="Column1" />
          <property name="Column4" type="int" />
        </join>
      </subclass>
    </subclass>
  </class>
```

Make sure you set the right discriminator values for each of the subclasses you intend to map. I suggest trying this and figure out whether it works better, or if this raised another problem. =)

Hope this helps! =)

Comment: Thank you pal, maybe it will solve the issue, I must test it :-)

Comment: I'm glad I could help! That is what SO is for. =)